# How to plot a wave like curve by using existing data?

Tags: plotting, fitting

I am trying to draw a time vs. position graph with these data:

```
t = {0, 0.47, 0.92, 1.37 ,1.8, 2.21} 
p = {0 ,11.3, 4.2, 10.5, 5, 9.5}
```

But since the data does not describe a regular sine curve, I do not know how to find the best fit.

I will be super appreciative if anyone can help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{0, 0}, {.47, 11.3}, {1.37, 4.2}, {1.8, 5}, {2.21, 9.5}};

dataplot = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True];

nmf = NonlinearModelFit[data, {b + c  Sin[d t + g]}, {b, c, d, g}, t];

modelplot = Plot[nmf[t], {t, 0, 2.21}, Style->Red];

Show[dataplot,modelplot]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to plot something like sine graph but diminishing at the end? Like a wave.

Comment: @user193754:  You must specify the functional form you seek to fit.  Otherwise we're just wasting time here.

Comment: $\sin\omega t\cdot c^t+C$

Comment: @user193754:  You should be able to see from my solution how to generalize to what you need.  You're on your own now!